# Parse in iOS8 & Swift deviceType must be specified

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform, ios8

Hi everybody I'm developing an app that it uses Parse for notifications. When i try to run the app it shows this error on log screen. 
[image]

I followed that documentation adding all the frameworks, certificates and of course i put the appId & clientId in Parse.setApplicationId()

I don't know the reason. I tried removing the app and installing again but it shows the same error.

If anybody could help me. Thank's.

Answer (score 1):

I think what you are missing is to run the `[PFIntallation currentInstalation]` after registering for push notifications. Here is what the documentation says about this method: Gets the currently-running installation from disk and returns an instance of it. If this installation is not stored on disk, returns a 'PFInstallation'
 with *deviceType* and *installationId* fields set to those of the
 current installation.

Here is an example of how to set it up:

In the AppDelegate of your app add the following method

```
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken:(NSData *)deviceToken {
   PFInstallation *currentInstallation = [PFInstallation currentInstallation];
   [currentInstallation addUniqueObject:@"global" forKey:@"channels"];
   [currentInstallation setDeviceTokenFromData:deviceToken];
   [currentInstallation saveInBackgroundWithBlock:^(BOOL succeeded, NSError *error) {
      if(error){
        NSLog(@"error saving parse current installation: %@", error);
      }
   }];
}
```